# Trivial subsigma algebra of the Borel algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be the unit interval $[0,1]$ equipped with the Borel algebra and the Lebesgue measure (restricted to the Borel algebra). I am trying to verify whether $P$ is 0-1 on the following sub-sigma algebra:

for each $x$, let $A_x=\{y\in [0,1]: y-x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. Clearly each $A_x$ is countable and therefore Borel. Moreover $\mathcal{A}=\{A_x: x\in[0,1]\}$ is a partition.

Let $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ denote the collection of $\mathcal{A}$-saturated sets (i.e.~$\mathcal{G}=\{F\in\mathcal{F}: \forall x, A_x\subset F\vee A_x\subset F^c\}$, equivalently the elements of $\mathcal{G}$ are borel sets that are unions of $A_x$'s). It is easy to verify that $\mathcal{G}$ is in fact a sigma-algebra.

I want to check if $P$ is 0-1 on $\mathcal{G}$. I can't find a way to apply either the Kolmogorov 0-1, Herwitt-Savage 0-1 or the ergodic theorem, and don't know any other way to prove this (or perhaps it is false - but I don't know how to show that either). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I think I have a proof idea, but it relies on certain assumptions that I am not sure are true. So I put it here for scrutiny:

Say a rational $q$ is an $n$-ary rational if $q=\frac{k}{n^i}$ for some $n, i, k$ (e.g.~$q$ is a dyadic rational if $q=\frac{k}{2^i}$). Let $A_x^{n}$ denote the set of $y\in[0,1]$ that differs from $x$ by an $n$-ary rational. Clearly $\mathcal{A}^n=\{A_x^n:x\in[0,1]\}$ also forms a partition and $A_x=\bigcup_nA_x^n$.

Now let $\mathcal{G}_n$ denote the collection of $\mathcal{A}^n$-saturated sets in $\mathcal{F}$. We claim that $P$ is 0-1 on $\mathcal{G}_n$ for all $n$. This is straightforward when $n=2$: identify $[0,1]$ with the Cantor space, then $\mathcal{G}_n$ is the tail-sigma-field generated by infinite iid coin tosses. I think the same reasoning applies to $n>2$.

Suppose the reasoning above is cogent. Then let $A\in\mathcal{G}$. Note that $A\in\mathcal{G}$ only if $A\in\mathcal{G}_n$ for all $n$. Since $P$ is 0-1 on $\mathcal{G}_n$, it follows that $P(A)\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathcal G$ is not clear.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oops sorry I meant for every $F\in\mathcal{G}$ rather than $F\in\mathcal{A}$. Has edited.